# I obtain different results in SQLSERVER using HashBytes with literal expression and with the value of the field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to update passwords of my SQL SERVER database.

Table users (login, password)

Code:

```
SELECT    
[login],
sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', [login]),1,0),
sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', 'usuario'),1,0)
FROM users
WHERE [login] = 'usuario';
```

The results are:

b63b34d5873bad93c92ec90c74ae0a4232e6473b
b665e217b51994789b02b1838e730d6b93baa30f

Note that "[login]" contains 'usuario' as value.

Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're `login` column is an `nvarchar` column and so the actual bytes involved are different.

See:

```
SELECT    
sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', N'usuario'),1,0),
sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', 'usuario'),1,0)
```

Results:

```
b63b34d5873bad93c92ec90c74ae0a4232e6473b
b665e217b51994789b02b1838e730d6b93baa30f
```

And see [Constants](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx):

> Unicode strings have a format similar to character strings but are preceded by an N identifier (N stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard). The N prefix must be uppercase. For example, `'Michél'` is a character constant while `N'Michél'` is a Unicode constant

Comment: thank you. However I need the other value, I suppose that I need to convert the nvarchar to varchar (login field). Edit: cast([login] as varchar).

Comment: @videador - it wasn't very clear from your question which direction things would need fixing up - but yes, doing a `CONVERT(varchar(length),[login])` may well be the fix you require.

Comment: Yes, that is another issue, the important thing is that the reason was that I was playing with a nvarchar field without knowning it (it is a database of a third and you know)